# VHDL indexed name issue

Tags: vhdl

i get this error in this code: ter.vhd(31): Cannot resolve indexed name (type ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_ULOGIC) as type std.STANDARD.BOOLEAN.
any idea how to fix it? 
i sincerly don't get what's wrong, tried with a web search, but nothing.
thanks in advance!

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY inverter IS
GENERIC(size: integer); 
PORT ( 
     a : IN std_ulogic_vector(size-1 DOWNTO 0);
     b : OUT std_ulogic_vector(size-1 DOWNTO 0);
     carry : OUT std_ulogic;
     mode : IN std_ulogic
   );
END ENTITY inverter;


ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF inverter IS
COMPONENT alu IS
GENERIC(size: integer); 
Port ( X : in  std_ulogic_VECTOR (size-1 downto 0);
       Y : in  std_ulogic_VECTOR (size-1 downto 0);
       SUM : out  std_ulogic_VECTOR (size-1 downto 0);
       CARRY : out std_ulogic);
end COMPONENT;

SIGNAL z, c : std_ulogic_VECTOR( size-1 downto 0);

BEGIN
start: process(a,mode)
begin
z <= (others => '0');

IF a(size-1) THEN
c <= not a; 
z(0) <=  '1';
ELSIF (mode = '1') THEN 
c <= not a; 
z(0) <=  '1';
ELSE
c <= a;
END IF;
end process;
alu1: alu 
generic map(size)
PORT MAP(x => c, y => z, sum => b, carry => carry);


END ARCHITECTURE behavioral;
```

Comment: Declaring `a` as an array of booleans would be one way to make it work, but you'd have to fix some other stuff too. Or learn how std_ulogic values are normally tested. Actually you already have an example of that in the same process.

Comment: @BrianDrummond The statement **IF a(size-1) THEN** is right ? I haven't encountered something like this before. Does this translate into "if a(size-1) is TRUE"? Also, the size variable shouldn't have been initialized?

Comment: `if <boolean> then` is fine. So, `IF a(size-1) THEN` is right if `a` is an array of booleans, which it could be, but currently isn't.  It's also right if you're using the implicit conversion operators in VHDL-2008, which I personally dislike because they blur the distinction between physical levels `'0'` and `'1'` and logical levels `true` and `false`, yielding absurdly confusing code if you're dealing with negative logic for example.

Comment: You could also note that were a to remain an in mode port with a subtype indication type mark of std_logic_vector that there's an equality operator ("=") that returns a boolean which can satisfy the requirement of an if statement condition, as in `IF To_bit(a(size-1)) = '1' THEN` where the To_bit function will also accept 'H' as true when translating a(size-1) to type BIT. (And that will analyze).

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008, 10.8 If statement *For the execution of an if statement, the condition specified after if, and any conditions specified after elsif, are evaluated in succession (treating a final else as elsif TRUE then) until one evaluates to TRUE or all conditions are evaluated and yield FALSE. If one condition evaluates to TRUE, then the corresponding sequence of statements is executed; ...* TRUE and FALSE are defined in 16.3 Package STANDARD as values of type BOOLEAN.